# Configuring Grub2

Tags: grub2

My problem is getting Grub2 to boot Ubuntu on my Windows7/Ubuntu 12.04 dual-boot system.

The background:

I have a computer that was delivered with Windows7 installed.

Following some advice from the internet, I decreased the size of the Windows partition to make space for Ubuntu.

I now have this:

```
/dev/sda1 NTFS 77 Gig Windows7 boot  

/dev/sda2 fat32 5.8 Gig shared  

/dev/sda3 Extended 383 Gig  

/dev/sda5 ext4 /boot 500Mb  

/dev/sda6 ext4 / 41 Gig  

/dev/sda7 linux-swap 4,1 Gig  

/dev/sda8 ext4 /home 336 Gig
```

I made use of EasyBCD to boot Windows or Ubuntu.

Windows7 boots fine.

When I try to boot Ubuntu, it stops at the GRUB prompt.

To boot Ubuntu I use the following:

```
root (hd0,4)
kernel /vmlinuz-3.5.0-23-generic root=/dev/sda6 ro
boot
```

and Ubuntu boots without problems. I am using it now.

My problem is that I don't know how to get GRUB to execute those 3 instructions automatically. I have read extensively but have to admit that I don't understand everything I see. I do lack experience and would appreciate some help.

I hope I am not repeating someone else's question but I am just not making progress.

Thanks in advance.

Victor

Comment: add them to /boot/grub/grub.cfg

Comment: Hi Mahmoud20070, I tried your suggestion and re-booted. I still get the GRUB prompt without an automatic boot. I can still boot manually and have done so. This is where my understanding of GRUB just runs out.

Comment: What steps did you take with EasyBCD? Where is GRUB installed?

Comment: It seems that GRUB is installed on /dev/sda5 ext4 /boot. I set up menu items in EasyBCD. Windows7 boots correctly. For Ubuntu, I set up GRUB2 in the Linux/BSD tab with Device: Automatically Configured. When I select Ubuntu at boot it gives me the GRUB prompt, so it looks like that part works, except that I don't know how to get GRUB to do the rest of the boot for me, instead of me doing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

[Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) is meant for fixing common boot problems. [Grub-customizer](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-grub-customizer-in-ubuntu-13-04.html) can also be helpful, since you know the boot command.

Comment: Problem solved. It was not a Grub2 issue at all. The problem was caused by me not configuring EasyBCD correctly. I don't think my question really belongs here. Sorry about that.